# Create a comma-separated strings in C#

Tags: c#, string-concatenation

I have an object which holds many values, and some of them (not all values from the object) need to be put in a [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) string. My approach was this:

```
string csvString = o.number + "," + o.id + "," + o.whatever ....
```

Is there is a better, more elegant way?

Comment: Generally speaking it's considered less efficient to concatenate strings with the `+` symbol. It creates more objects to be garbage collected.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

If you put all your values in an array, at least you can use `string.Join`.

```
string[] myValues = new string[] { ... };
string csvString = string.Join(",", myValues);
```

You can also use the overload of `string.Join` that takes `params string` as the second parameter like this:

```
string csvString = string.Join(",", value1, value2, value3, ...);
```

Comment: +1 for using an array in between which keeps the code more legible when there are more than "a few" values.

Comment: @Bazzz - Yes, it might quickly get messy if you enter 10+ parameters into the join method call. I think the first approach is the cleanest one, but for a few values, the second one is also ok.

Comment: Why two downvotes on this answer? A reason would be appreciated so everyone knows what you feel are the problem with this answer.

Comment: Yeah one was from me (sorry lol). He doesn't have his values in an array and it's just unnecessary to use an array as an intermediate step to building the string. It's inefficient and makes the code longer (and imho no more readable). I prefer just using the `Join` directly (as your update).

Comment: @fearofawhackplanet - Thanks for giving a reason. Gives more sense that way ;) You are of course entiteled to your own opinion. I just like to hear it ;)

Comment: +1 for using an array; it's neater and functionality can be extended more easily.

Comment: @fear: `string.Join` uses a params array.  Meaning code that passes the parameters in directly will be converted to use an array automatically by the compiler.  There is no difference between the calls as far as overheads are concerned.

Comment: This is not strictly the correct answer for CSV strings. True CSV will escape strings as needed.

Comment: What should I do if value contains comma, for e.g. I've values like test1, test2 and test, test3 where test, test3 should be consider as a single value.

Answer (score 15):

Another approach is to use the CommaDelimitedStringCollection class from System.Configuration namespace/assembly. It behaves like a list plus it has an overriden ToString method that returns a comma-separated string.

Pros - More flexible than an array.

Cons - You can't pass a string containing a comma.

```
CommaDelimitedStringCollection list = new CommaDelimitedStringCollection();

list.AddRange(new string[] { "Huey", "Dewey" });
list.Add("Louie");
//list.Add(",");

string s = list.ToString(); //Huey,Dewey,Louie
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join.aspx) method to do something like `string.Join(",", o.Number, o.Id, o.whatever, ...)`.

edit: As digEmAll said, string.Join is faster than StringBuilder. They use an external implementation for the string.Join.

Profiling code (of course run in release without debug symbols):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        string r;
        int iter = 10000;

        string[] values = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "a little bit longer please", "one more time" };

        sw.Restart();
        for (int i = 0; i < iter; i++)
            r = Program.StringJoin(",", values);
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("string.Join ({0} times): {1}ms", iter, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        sw.Restart();
        for (int i = 0; i < iter; i++)
            r = Program.StringBuilderAppend(",", values);
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("StringBuilder.Append ({0} times): {1}ms", iter, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static string StringJoin(string seperator, params string[] values)
    {
        return string.Join(seperator, values);
    }

    static string StringBuilderAppend(string seperator, params string[] values)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.Append(values[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
            builder.Append(seperator);
            builder.Append(values[i]);
        }
        return builder.ToString();
    }
}
```

string.Join took 2ms on my machine and StringBuilder.Append 5ms. So there is noteworthy difference. Thanks to digAmAll for the hint.

Comment: `string.Join` is as fast as `StringBuilder` (if not slightly faster) because they both allocate one string only

Comment: The problem with normal string concat (eg. using string1 += string2) is that the original string1 is thrown away (since strings are immutable), and the new sum of string1 and string2 is pointed by string1, and that is not very efficient if done repeatedly. However, as digEmAll also points out, string.Join of course only allocate the string once. Not once for each element in the array.

Comment: One disadvantage of `string.Join` (until .NET 4.0) is that it requires an array of strings, forcing you to allocate one if you have only a generic `IEnumerable<string>`... anyway .NET 4.0 has fixed this problem

Comment: You are right I edited my post. But I wonder which external method is called for string.Join as it is a native implementation and not inside mscorlib?

Comment: @jb_: actually (my fault) I checked only .net 2 `string.Join` implementation, and those 2 overloads (taking `string[]`) make use of an external method called `FastAllocateString` that is (maybe sometimes) slightly faster. Surprisingly (for me), the new `string.Join` overloads introduced with .net 4, simply use a `StringBuilder` internally! So basically there's no difference between the 2 methods, then, my suggestion is to use `string.Join()` for simplicity (and for the "don't reinvent the wheel" principle)

Comment: @digEmAll: But the basics are still corecct, so there is no need for excuses :-). The string.Join(string, string[]) and string.Join(string, string[], int, int) overloads are still use  FastAllocateString and thus maybe faster than the other overloads of string.Join. But I agree to the preferable usage of string.Join rather than implementing own Join-Logic with a StringBuilder.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using .NET 4 you can use the overload for `string.Join` that takes an IEnumerable if you have them in a List, too:

```
string.Join(", ", strings);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could override your object's ToString() method:

```
public override string ToString ()
{
    return string.Format ("{0},{1},{2}", this.number, this.id, this.whatever);
}
```

Comment: This is only useful if he knows exactly the number of elements he want to put in the string however. string.Join is probably a better fit.

Comment: Yes but since he wants to create a csv file, the elements will most likely be the same every time. I don't know, it's a matter of preference.

Comment: I assumed from the question that he always want the same fields so he definately does know the number of elements. Nothing wrong with this answer although I don't really like overriding ToString here as it may  not be general purpose enough. +1 from me anyway.

Comment: @fearofawhackplanet - Nothing wrong with it. Just a matter of preference ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, there can be multiple ways to do this.**

If you have `List/Array` of `strings` then you can adopt it;

```
string[] myStrings = new string[] { "Hi", "stackoverflow", };
string csvString = string.Join(",", myStrings);  // csvString :: Hi,stackoverflow
```

If you have multiple `strings` then you can adopt it;

```
string st1 = "Hi";
string st2 = "stackoverflow";
string st3 = "team";
string csvString = string.Join(",", st1, st2, st3);  // csvString :: Hi,stackoverflow,team
```