# Convert existing IEnumerable<int> to string (#,#,#,..) via Method

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable, var

I'm trying to convert an `IEnumerable<int>` to a string in the format `#,#,#,..`.  I'm having a terrible time attempting to make a method of this.  What is a quick and easy way to handle?

Thanks.

Comment: What was the problem with what you've tried? Have you searched ["create comma separated string"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4884050/284240)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `String.Join`:

```
string result = string.Join(",", enumerable);
```

Comment: This is only available starting at `.net 4` [check out 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String.Join(v=vs.90).aspx).

Comment: @allonhadaya Correct.  You'd need to add your own overload, or first convert the sequence into a string array, if you were on an older version.

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about something like:

```
string.Join(",", e.Select(i=>i.ToString()).ToArray());
```

i.e., concatenating an enumerable of `int`s (`e` in this case)?